# This elementary example of sentential calculus in an encyclopedia article (SEP) escapes me

Tags: logic

The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy [cites the following example](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-syllogism/#Boet) of "sentential logic" as an evidently "invalid deduction":

**Premise 1: A ⊃ (B ⊃ C)**

**Premise 2: B ⊃ ∼C**

**Conclusion: ∼A**

But assuming the logical operator symbolized there ("⊃") is material implication, what is wrong with the logic chain?
Seems like a pretty basic nested [*modus tollens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) to me....

From the explanatory paragraph that follows in that article, the explanation seems to be that it is a valid *inference* in *term logic*, but **not** a valid *deduction* in *sentential logic*.  But I don't see why the validity would be affected by whether the referents of the symbols be terms or sentences.

Comment: Can you link to the article that claims this is "invalid"?

Comment: Sorry for the oversight, @alias.  I thought I had.  Is now included; first hyperlink

Comment: I fail to see how this is a programming question.  We usually allow questions about Boolean algebra but propositional calculus and higher-order logics are usually delegated to one of the math forums.

Comment: @RBarryYoung,
Not sure I understand; the only identifiers for this question are the two tags, "logic" & "first-order-logic".  Are you suggesting I remove the "first-order-logic" tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `A` to be true, and `B` to be false. Both hypotheses are true, but not the conclusion. Hence the deduction is invalid.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you!
So I guess since TERMS, taken alone, are not themselves T/F, the sentence reflects a "valid inference in term logic", whereas when SENTENCES are the arguments, being necessarily T/F they render the material implication elaborated here not valid, as you've shown.